# c# Multiple applications in same folder. Cannot deploy DLL (locked)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, explorer

In our company we have all programs in one central directory which is shared over the network. (Drive "X:")

Advantages:

- configuration files are centralised
- simple deploy of programs

Problem: We are using librarys (dll) for central functions. When a program which refers to one of the dll's is opened on a client, it's not possible to replace it with a newer version since the file is locked.

At the beginning it was possible to bypass the lock by renaming the file. But since Windows 7 appeared, the file can only seldom be renamed. We currently have to disconnect all clients to unlock and replace the file.

I searched for hours on the web for a solution to unlock the file. But found nothing which was working.

Do you have ideas how we could bypass/resolve this issue? We are using .NET (C#).

Comment: One strategy is to copy the files from the central directory to a local directory and run them from there, with an update check on startup to see if there is a more recent version available.

Comment: This is an good idea but cannot be accomplished by the program/framework itself, right?

Comment: That's right, except I suppose for ClickOnce which does a similar thing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with ClickOnce. It looks like it could solve our problems. I will give it a try and report here.